# How to calculate when a diminished value reaches a certain point?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, math, logarithm

I'm sure ive had this in school before, but i cant remember what is this thing called as.

I have arbitrary number and i need to know how many times i can multiply it by 0.9 (or any other value 0-1) until theres less than x left from the original number.

in a loop format it would look like:

```
num = 4654;
mult = 0.9;
limit = 140;
count = 0;
while(num >= limit){
    num *= mult;
    count++;
}
```

But is this even possible to be done without a loop? something with logarithms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that

```
num * (0.9)^k <= limit
```

is the inequality you wish to satisfy for some integer `k`, and you seek the smallest such `k`. Then

```
(0.9)^k <= limit / num
```

and

```
k * log(0.9) <= log(limit / num)
```

so that

```
k >= log(limit / num) / log(0.9)
```

where the inequality reverses because `log(0.9) < 0`. Thus, take the smallest integer `k` larger than `log(limit / num) / log(0.9)`.

So, take the ceiling of `log(limit / num) / log(0.9)`.

Of course, this generalizes by replacing `0.9` by `r` where `r` is your multiplier from `(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

count = log(limit / num) / log(mult)